Is there a Amelia Earhart anniversary late August 2024?
Today it came to my attention that in the last few days (late August 2024), there have been two concept albums centred on Amelia Earhart's last flight announced and shortly to be released by Laurie Anderson and Public Service Broadcasting
Neither mention why they released at this date.
Is there some anniversary of some event that would make sense of the timing or is in just a coincidence? Has some copyright expired on original recordings?

I think the speech on the (excellent) Public Service Broadcasting track is a recording artist that they used specifically for the track. It's not an original of Earhart's voice. So, the copyright idea might not be right. Source: interview with PSB on BBC Radio 6Music, in session with Steve Lamacq, 30th September (yesterday, as I write this!) https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/m00234hb?partner=uk.co.bbc&origin=share-mobile

(should have mentioned: the PSB track about Earhart that I'm referencing is called "Electre")

Although there are no officially stated holiday for Amelia Earhart in late August, there is an official holiday for her on July 24 every year, the day she was born.
There is one possible reason for the August releases, though. In August 1928, Earhart became the first woman to fly solo across the North American continent and back. Thus, it is possible that these albums decided to commemorate her by her achievements rather than birthday. This is just a guess, though, and the release dates may well have been completely unrelated to any holidays or commemoration days.
